# Assign a value to a column if values exist in others

Tags: r, dataframe

#### First Question

Given the following data frame:

```
col_1 <- c(1, NA, 2, 3)
col_2 <- c(2, 1, 1, 2)
col_3 <- c(3, 2, 3, NA)
df <- data.frame(value_1, value_2, value_3)

col_1    col_2   col_3
    1       2       3
   NA       1       2
    2       1       3
    3       2      NA
```

I want to do something like this: If there is data that exists in df[1,1], df[1,2] and df[1,3], flag that row as 1. Otherwise flag it as 0. Therefore, you could get something like this:

```
col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
    1     2     3     1
   NA     1     2     0 
    2     1     3     1
    3     2    NA     0
```

#### Second question

Alternatively, maybe I have this df:

```
col_1 <- c(1, NA, 2, 3)
col_2 <- c(NA, 1, 1, NA)
col_3 <- c(3, 2, 3, NA)
df <- data.frame(col_1, col_2, col_3)

col_1    col_2   col_3
    1       NA      3
   NA       1       2
    2       1       3
    3       NA     NA
```

And I want to create a variable where if values exist in col_1 and col_3, I assign a value of 1. Otherwise I assign a 0. So it would look something like this:

```
col_1    col_2   col_3   col_4
    1       NA       3       1
   NA      1        2       0
   NA      1        3       0
    3       NA      NA       0
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Hi great question. The second example data does not match the second answer data

Comment: Second one: `as.numeric(rowSums(!is.na(df[,-2]), na.rm = TRUE) == NCOL(df[,-2]))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` either on the subset of columns of data or on the whole dataset

```
df$col_4 <- as.integer(rowSums(!is.na(df[c(1, 3)]))==2)
```

---

Another option is `Reduce` on the whole dataset

```
df$col_4 <- as.integer(!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, is.na)))
```

or on subset of columns

```
df$col_4 <- as.integer(!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[c(1, 3)], is.na)))
df$col_4
#[1] 1 0 0 0
```